# How to specify a port in connection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

My server uses port#1988
But I don't see any option in connection wizard where I can mention the port number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TCP connection string options are described in [Creating a Valid Connection String Using TCP/IP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191260.aspx):

> connection string in the format
>   `tcp:<servername>[\<instancename>],<port>` or
>   `tcp:<IPAddress>[\<instancename>],<port>`.

So you need to put this as the machine name in the connection wizard: `tcp:machine,1988`